# Problem with configuring Thunderbird with hMailServer

Tags: email, thunderbird, hmail-server

I installed hMailServer and did the following

```
  1. Created a test.com domain
  2. Added an user testuser
```

Now the hMailServer is running in my localhost.

When I install Mozilla thunder bird and try to configure it by entering the username and password, it fails giving

```
  Thunderbird failed to find the settings for your email account.
```

How can I tell thunderbird about the hMailServer running in my local host? Where is thunderbird looking for the domain when I entered testuser@test.com?

I saw some messages like "Looking up in Mozilla ISP database". But the mail server is in my local machine.

Am I missing any configuration details?

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

### I posted a video tutorial on YouTube on how to configure hMail and Thunderbird: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMPfcVd6OOk

I found it pay attention to the IPv4 address -that is very important :
http://www.mjvanderwielen.com/?p=1632

Make sure:
Incoming is:  ”IMAP”

Server hostname: [local ip address server computer](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-out-Your-IP-Address)

Port: 143

SSL: None

Authentication: Normal password

Username: complete account name!!

Outgoing:  ”SMTP”

Server hostname: as per your host

Port: as per your host

SSL: as per your host

Authentication: as per your host